# Script running from terminal after setting pythonpath and running "thonny&" command, but not when thonny ide is opened directly

Tags: raspbian, script, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, ide, libcamera

I am using a Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit to run a script that will capture an image. I have gone through installing the right packages for libcamera for this OS and can run libcamera apps using my terminal.
I get the error: no module named picamera2 whenever I try to run the script in thonny ide.

However, I have set my pythonpath variable to

```
/home/pi/picamera2:/home/pi/libcamera/build/src/py:/home/pi/kmsxx/build/py:/home/pi/python-v4l2
```

and when I run the command "thonny&" or "thonny" from my terminal, my script runs without an error

Please, how can I be able to run my scripts without having to go through this process?

Answer (score 0):

`thonny` is an integrated development environment for Python that is designed for beginners. If you just want to run a python program forget `thonny` and just run with python!

All my python scripts start with:-

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
```

so they can be run from terminal.

Alternately just run `python3 scriptname`

Comment: hi, milliways. thank you, I'll do that. I wanted to know if there was a way it could be run from thonny itself, cause i'm making changes to my code, and it'll be easier if I could be testing directly from the ide.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Environment variable in Thonny under (Tools:Options:General), which will persist after a closedown/restart of Thonny.